# How to create a simple app that displays weather details

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview

I want to create a simple weather app that displays the weather details for three consecutive days.

When I click on the weather tab the weather details for three consecutive days should be shown on a table view. How is this possible? Can anybody provide me any links regarding this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Well, we are not going to write the code for you, but if you want guidance as to how to get weather data I would look into Yahoo's Weather API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use Google API to get weather detail
please have a look on [Google API](http://wiki.wunderground.com/index.php/API_-_XML)

Comment: it return in xml format . google API take input as latitude longotude (of user Current location), or location name. or latitutue longitude and date . in XML it returns weather info

Comment: try this in mozila or IE browser http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=jakarta&hl=enhttp://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=jakarta&hl=en

Comment: If you go with this route keep in mind that this is an unofficial API that might be removed at any time.

Answer (score 0):

[Weather Decision Technologies](http://www.wdtinc.com/) also provides several APIs for weather feed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an app, you have to start thinking on what you'll need. If you want to develop an app for iOS, use a mac, if you want to develop for Android, use a Mac or Windows. If you want to create an application for iOS, you will first need to download Xcode from the Mac app store for free. If you want to create an application for Android, you will need to download Android Studio and SDK with Java.

iOS -

You'll need to learn Swift, Apples new programming language to develop apps. UIKit will be necessary for apps. You will need to download a weather tracking framework from the web. Then you will need to implement it into UIKit and deploy your application.

Android -

You'll need to learn Java and XML, Androids programming languages. You'll still need to download a weather tracking framework from the web and implement it into your app using Androids User Interface tools.

Online Cloud Storage -

For lots of things in your app, you'll probably need a web storage option to make users, save and load data through and from a local server you'll be hosting, and make network connections. For this, you will have to use a website database server named Parse. This free tool will be available for iOS and Android at the same time.

Other Options -

If you are planning to create an app one time and release it on all platforms, you might want to use some other development platforms than the normal ones provided by the operating systems SDK. Some other options include ionic SDK (JavaScript/HTML5), Unity3d(C#, JavaScript), Unreal Engine 4(C++/Visual Scripting), or and other game engines.

I hope this helped you make and deploy your first app! If you become popular, remember I helped you!

Comment: Google API's are a great option to add in your application as well. Since I just heard you were making an app for iOS, you'll need to learn how to implement Googles dev tools into your project. Google is one of the only options you can use for making a map app.

Comment: [link](http://www.aerisweather.com/blog/aeris-ios-weather-framework-1-1-7-released/)

Comment: [Check This Out For Help](http://www.aerisweather.com/blog/aeris-ios-weather-framework-1-1-7-released/)